# Windows 10 and linux mint on one ssd disk, how to restore windows partition without losing linux?

Tags: linux, partition, windows, grub2, boot-loader

I accidentally entered `sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sda1` in terminal,
and now i am unable to boot with Windows.

I have Windows and Linux installed on ssd. On startup i have screen where i can select which to boot.

At the top i see `GNU GRUB, version 2.02`. And have variants which to load - Linux or Windows.

Is it possible to restore Windows partition and enable it to load?

Windows is recommended to be installed first, and then Linux.

If it is possible to fix, will all things work as usual? I don't want to lose my Linux data and Windows.

Here is the screen from gparted:

[image]

If i have another empty/clear/new SSD disk, how can i from the running now linux can move the windows to the new ssd ?

Comment: Provide the complete partition style in your system. Which one has Linux distro, which one has windows, which has EFI etc. And their partition styles.

Comment: @Biswapriyo  i have added gparted screen,  do you mean this? Or some additional info required?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sda1` will zero out a partition, so your Windows boot partition is gone. Luckily, your data should all still exist on /dev/sda2 if I understand the image you shared.

You will need to recover the Windows boot partition with the Microsoft equivalent of a rescue disc. Once you can boot windows again, you should be able to re-add the entry that points to your Linux partitions.

Comment: If i have another empty ssd (new) how can i for now from running linux move the windows to the new ssd?